# Set thread number limitation

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a multi thread download app.

Each thread opens a new connection and does download stuffs.

I want to not have more than 4 connection for downloading a file.

Her is my code in `download()` :

```
private void download() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("thread active Count: " + Thread.activeCount());
    }
}
```

But thread active count reaches to `10` !

here is the result:

```
thread active Count: 3
thread active Count: 4
thread active Count: 5
thread active Count: 6
thread active Count: 7
thread active Count: 8
thread active Count: 9
thread active Count: 10
```

I want to have just `4` connection (thread) for a particular file.

Comment: Have you tried using a [fixed thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-)?

Comment: ^^ make 4 threads, that's it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, how can use it?

Comment: @Ghkjnsadxzcx you noticed that HFOE's comment has some blue text?

Comment: @MartinJames I'm actually trying to do it in the for loop

Comment: @Ghkjnsadxzcx `Thread.activeCount()` returns nr of threads which includes JVM system threads (GC thread, and so on). Don't worry about it.